# Yii 2 Swiftmailer emails goin to spam

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer, spam

I am using Swiftmailer to send out HTML and sometimes Text emails.
The emails will sometimes end up in the Spam folder of the recipients.
I am using SMTP Transport to connect to a remote mail server to send the emails.

We have a web app hosted on a domain and it will connect to the users email address and authenticate and then send out the email.

I cannot seem to figure out why some of the emails end up in Spam or Junk folder?

Here is my Swiftmailer config code:

```
    'mailer' => [
        'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
        'useFileTransport'=>false,
        'transport' => [
            'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'mail.thehostname.com',
            'username' => 'system@thehostname.com',
            'password' => 'PASSWORD_HERE',
            'port' => '465',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
             'streamOptions' => [ 'ssl' =>
                    [ 'allow_self_signed' => true,
                        'verify_peer' => false,
                        'verify_peer_name' => false,
                    ],
                ],
        ],
    ],
```

On sending an actual email - this is how i setup the message:

```
        //set up the transport
        $transport = Yii::$app->mailer->getTransport();
        if($user->smtp_port=="587")
        {
            $transport
                ->setUserName($user->email)
                ->setPassword($user->imappassword)
                ->setHost($user->smtp_url)
                ->setPort($user->smtp_port)
                ->setEncryption('tls');                    
        } else {
            $transport
                ->setUserName($user->email)
                ->setPassword($user->imappassword)
                ->setHost($user->smtp_url)
                ->setPort($user->smtp_port)
                ->setEncryption('ssl');     
        }

        //setup headers
        $mid = "<".time()." TheSystem@".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].">";
        $message->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Organization', $user->company->name);
        $message->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('MIME-Version', '1.0');
        $message->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('X-Mailer', 'PHP v' . phpversion());
        $message->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()
        ->addParameterizedHeader('Content-type', 'text/html', ['charset' => 'utf-8']);
        $message->getSwiftMessage()->getHeaders()->addTextHeader('Message-ID', $mid);

        $message
            ->setFrom([$user->email=>$user->fullname]);
```

From this point onwards $message is passed on and used as needed to add Text / HTML content and then $message->send() is called

Are my headers Correct? Is it causing mail to go to spam?

Ive already scoured through Stackoverflow and added Headers that i found in other stackoverflow posts. It seemed to help a little but mails still going to spam.

Id like to have my mail not go to spam or junk.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: this is probably because you are using `from_email` that belongs to a domain other than the one you are using to send the emails i.e `Gmail` .In the past, this hasn’t been a big problem. The service provider would just set the “from” address to the customer’s email address and send the email. This email might be hosted on the customer’s domain (e.g. example.com) or it might be an outlook.com or gmail.com address. But there’s a big imminent problem with this use case because it’s going to stop working entirely no matter what ISP you are sending to.

Comment: Hi, The From email will always match the domain the mail is sent from. We use the customers email address - someone@example.com. Our server connects to example.com and authenticates and sends the mail via example.com logged with the users email address + password.